# ошибка в методе по расчету сопротивления резисторов

Tags: java

```
public class mail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        double result;
        double []array = new double[] {3.9,4.7};
        result =findRes(array);
                private static double findRes(double[] arr) {
                    double sum = 0;
                    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                        sum += (1/(1/arr[i]));
                    }
            return sum;
        }
}
```

Пишу программку для расчета резисторов подключенных параллельно.
на входе получаю массив со значениями типа double и считаю их выводя итог.
"Идея" возмущается,что не может решить метод findRes, но когда прошу создать его (alt+enter) она делает такой же как у меня, еще она красным выделяет скобку  в самом методе перед double и не может вернуть "пустое значение"(это она про sum внутри метода), где ошибка?

Comment: Ну и до кучи - кассы принято именовать с большой буквы. Не `mail`, а `Mail`

Comment: Вы объявили метод `fundRes` ВНУТРИ метода `main`. Это неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так выглядит корректный код этого класса:

```
public class Mail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double[]{3.9, 4.7};
        double result = findRes(array);
    }

    private static double findRes(double[] arr) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += (1 / (1 / arr[i]));
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```